# How to stop running code in Eclipse?

Tags: 12.04, eclipse

I'm  on `Ubuntu` and using `Eclipse` and i run code with infinite loop and eclipse not responding to me .
I tried to stop by `red square` but didn't work !!!
How can i stop it ?

Which Command can i use it in Terminal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can open a terminal, I'd suggest to kill the `eclipse` process:

```
pkill eclipse
```